# How to remove the leading and trailing whitespace in flutter TextField?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

Flutter TextField Whitespace UI

[image]

How do I remove the leading and trailing space to match the above UI container?

```
Container(decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                          Radius.circular(10),
                        ),
                        color: Color(0xFFD9D9D9),
                      ),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        maxLines: 1,
                        expands: false,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          hintText: _auth.user.uid,
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey.shade500),
                          isDense: true,
                          contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0, vertical: 12),
                          border: InputBorder.none,
                        ),
                        style: const TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 12,
                            backgroundColor: Color(0xFFD9D9D9)),
                      ),
                    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not center the text. Remove `TextAlign.center`.